# Why doesn't array_filter() mutate my strings while it iterates?

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

So I have the following array:

```
array:3 [
  0 => "6.05"
  1 => "5.94"
  2 => "5.96"
]
```

Which is passed through the following function:

```
$filteredShots = array_filter($shots, function($shot) {
        if (is_numeric($shot)) {
            return floatval($shot);
        }
});
```

Which then spits out, the exact same array:

```
array:3 [
  0 => "6.05"
  1 => "5.94"
  2 => "5.96"
]
```

Why are these still strings? I told it to convert them to `floatval`. Am I doing something wrong? Am I crazy?

If I die and dump on the return statement I get: 6.05, not "6.05" so ... why is the array reflecting that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_filter` expects `true` or `false` from the callback function to retain or remove the corresponding element.  In your implementation, unless you have a `0` or falsey value it will always return `true`.  You want `array_map` that actually applies the return of the callback:

```
$filteredShots = array_map(function($shot) {
        if (is_numeric($shot)) {
            return floatval($shot);
        }
}, $shots);
```

You can also modify the original array using `array_walk`:

```
array_walk($shots, function(&$shot) {
        if (is_numeric($shot)) {
            $shot = floatval($shot);
        }
});
```

You can use `array_filter` to remove non-numeric:

```
$filteredShots = array_filter($shots, function($shot) {
        return is_numeric($shot) ? true : false;
});
//or simply
$filteredShots = array_filter($shots, 'is_numeric');
```

Comment: @TheWebs That's what documentation is for, although the function names seem to describe what they do pretty clearly. Filtering means to reduce a  collection to just the items that match some criteria.