# problem in array_filter() and strlen function

Tags: php

Please consider this line of code:

```
$arr = array_filter(explode('/', $path), 'strlen');
```

and suppose `$path` variable is a url like:

```
$path = "http://localhost/oldcodes/test_codes/";
```

I expect the output of first code would be something like:

```
array(4) { [0]=> "5"  [2]=> "9"  [3]=> "8" [4]=> "10" }
```

because `strlen` function returns length of each string, BUT I get this result:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "http:" [2]=> string(9) "localhost" [3]=> string(8) "oldcodes" [4]=> string(10) "test_codes" }
```

could you please give me any hint why the result is in this way!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically "your problem" is because `explode` breaks down a string using a `delimiter` from a string in your case you are using `/` this means in your case you have the following string:

```
http://localhost/oldcodes/test_codes/
```

Breaking the string using the `/` separator would return.

- http
- ''
- 'localhost'
- 'oldcodes'
- 'test_codes'
- ''

When the output of this function is passed down to `array_filter`  this function would return any value that is evaluated to `true` using loose comparisision in this case empty strings are considered false and not empty strings are evaluated to `true` that's why empty strings are removed from your output. [Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

You can always pass a `callback` (another function) as second parameter to `array_filter` to filter specif elements instead, or to define a custom logic to filter elements out of an array.

And if you are looking to get the length of each of those components you need to swap `array_filter` with `array_map` instead.

```
$arr = array_map( 'strlen', array_filter( explode('/', $path) ) );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great explanation. my question is when an element passed to array_filter by `strlen` as a callback function, if the element length is greater than zero then why `strlen` function does not return the length of the element??! as this is the default behavior of this function!

Comment: Great question, `array_filter` does not return the output of the function you use (in your case `strlen`) `array_filter` only uses the function you passed to evaluate the current value in the array if the value evaluates to true (in your case any length != 0 would be `true`) and all of those elemenets that evaluates to `true` are returned as they are no change is applied to the original values that's why you need to use `array_map` which does exactly that maps over an array and returns the output of the function you passed for each element instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just you need to use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) instead array_filter:

```
<?php
$path = "http://localhost/oldcodes/test_codes/";

$arr = array_map(
    'strlen',
    explode('/', $path)
);

var_dump($arr);
```

[Here the code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=9e92cdaecaeccd0edb1e90f0140e2ed6&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)