# Manipulate array filter in php value array not change

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, api, array-filter

I have array an array with this value

```
array:11 [
 "id" => 4
  "title" => "CLUSTER AIRING"
  "channel_title" => "CLUSTER AIRING"
  "parent_id" => 2
  "start_date" => "2022-09-30 10:59:00"
  "end_date" => "2022-09-30 13:58:00"
  "image_url" => "https://stag-sections-image.visionplus.id/media/"
  "content_core_id" => 2
  "type" => "Channel"
  "content_type" => "Channel"
  "is_upcoming" => true
]
```

I already make this code to filter start_date & end_date this filter already works. but when I changed the value`is_upcoming` from true to it's not changed. but when I make `dd()` to `$item` this is already changed to false. Here is my code

```
$data = array_values(array_filter($data, function($item){
       if (($item['start_date']) <= now() && ($item['end_date'] >= now()) ) {
               $item['is_upcoming'] = false;
               return $item;
       }
       if ($item['start_date'] > now()) {
               $item['is_upcoming'] = true;
               return $item;
           }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback is used to return a boolean value to determine whether to include or exclude the object/value in [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). But you're using it to return the entire data which makes the callback always return true. Use `array_map()` instead of `array_filter()`.

```
$data = array_map(function($item){
    if (($item['start_date']) <= now() && ($item['end_date'] >= now()) ) {
        $item['is_upcoming'] = false;
        return $item;
    }
    if ($item['start_date'] > now()) {
        $item['is_upcoming'] = true;
        return $item;
    }
}, $data);
```